# Conversion of nested for loop into lambda or pandas join/merge format

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two dataframes one has 4.7 million rows and other has 1 million rows.  I need to join those two data frames base upon some conditions. but using for loop the operation takes a lot of time. How to convert my for loop code into efficient pandas query?

```
su_rating_range = [0] *len(tb_su_name)
for x in xrange(len(tb_su_name)):
    print "tb count--",x
    for y in xrange(len(su_su_name)):
        if tb_su_name[x] == su_su_name[y] and tb_year_week[x] == su_year_week[y] and tb_tg_mkt[x] == su_tg_mkt[y]:
            print "su count--",y
            su_rating_range[x] = su_ratings[y]
tb_concate_ratings["LAG_RATING_su"] = su_rating_range
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) function of `pandas` you can try :

```
result = tb.merge(su, how = 'inner', on = ['su_name', 'year_week', 'tg_mkt'])
```